# Is it good practice to create classes for specific settings?

Tags: c#, class, serialization, settings

I have a Windows Form Application that I'm currently writing.

Now, this application will interact with the user via TextBoxs and so on.

I designed 4 classes to save all the settings needed (this would be DirectorySettings, LoopSettings, AttackSettings and AutoPotSettings), this will be used to save values from the textbox and such.

I made them all Serializable.

My plan would be to save those classes to later restore them and load the settings defined on them, so they could persist during various application sessions.

My question is, is this good practice or is there anyother way to do this?

This settings values will be used multiple times during run-time and I'd like my users to be able to save them for later sessions.

EDIT: This question arised when I read about Properties.Settings to save settings. I'm not sure I should use that feature, or if I should use my own classes to save those.

Comment: You can use your own classes for saving settings in the  `Properties.Settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sense.  Maybe create a userprofile class that houses all user related things regarding game state ..  Then serialize that one object.   U can tie to a usercode so when they login,  they get all state related info back

It allows for people to have multiple users/games etc vs a single state

Comment: This application will be used for a single game,but could have various user settings, but I'd like to save information like for example: Buy 500 Hp Pots. This would be saved on the LoopSettings, and if the user closes the application and opens it up again, I'd like that number to be loaded, so the user doesn't have to configure the application multiple times.
From what I understood you meant to tell me to make a new class, that would house an instance of each of this classes, and then I would serialize that single class?

Comment: Correct. An overall object that has your classes

Comment: I edited my main post to add the reason why I made the question. Could you explain me if I should use my way (multiple classes for each type of settings, saving them as an object that contains all the settings classes) or if I should use Properties.Settings to save those?

Comment: the danger of serislized objects is that u could change the class substantially to render deserialization troublesome in theory

Comment: uhm I see, so it would be troublesome to make 'multiple-version' wide settings? as In, changing those classes from v0.01 to v0.02 (additional stuff in the classes) could render the previous user-settings useless?

Comment: You could simply have a properties file that has all the attributes to allow u to recreate the state.  Then read that into a newly created userprofile that has the mechanics to recreate the objects u need in the proper state

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for your time! You've answered my doubts! Thank you.

Comment: Your choice. I have done both.  I prefer properties type file.  Then have a class signature that takes a properties type object and have a private rebuildstateofuser method to get it right.  This avoids any serislization issues long term

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Class design,  you can use interface/Abstract class for defining Saving/Reading behaviour, like **IGameState** Interface mentioned below. It has 2 methods a) **SaveState** b) **ReadState** for Saving and reading state.

Then your class DirectorySettings, LoopSettings, AttackSettings, AutoPotSettings can implement the interface. In your main program, you would be able to define an abstraction as highlighted in Main method below so that the Main program code is decoupled from the list of Settings.

If you have lot of settings and you need more control this approach should help in extending the system easily.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<IGameState> lstSaveState = new List<IGameState>();
            // For Saving State
            lstSaveState.ForEach(x=>x.SaveState());

        // For Reading State
        lstSaveState.ForEach(x => x.ReadState());
    }

}

public interface IGameState
{
    void SaveState();

    IGameState ReadState();
}


public class DirectorySettings : IGameState
{
    public void SaveState()
    {
        // Serialize
    }

    public IGameState ReadState()
    {
        // Deserialize
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class LoopSettings : IGameState
{
    public void SaveState()
    {
        // Serialize
    }

    public IGameState ReadState()
    {
        // Deserialize
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for the code. It will help me to solve my problems. I'll try to implement my own version of such idea.